# Download file from Google Drive API with PHP Slim API

Tags: php, angularjs, google-api, slim

I have developed a PHP Slim API Webservice from where i access my Google Drive Files and return them to my Angular Frontend. Now am not sure which is the best way to download my files from Google drive.
 1. Can i directly download a file to my Browser from the GuzzleHTTP stream?
 2. Or do i have to save the file to my server first before download?

Please tell me which way is better and how i can accomplish that?

My code so far:

```
$fileId = filter_var($data['id']);

$param = array(
             'alt' => 'media' ,
             'mimeType'=> $mimeType
             );

            $content = $client->files->get($fileId, $param);

    ***<here i want to process the file and download it to my browser>***
```

Then finally how can handle download in angular.js?

Answer (score 0):

Inside a route, this should work:

```
echo $content;
return $response->withHeader('Content-Description', 'File Transfer')
    ->withHeader('Content-Type', $mimeType)
    ->withHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="'.$yourFileName.'"')
    ->withHeader('Expires', '0')
    ->withHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate')
    ->withHeader('Pragma', 'public')
    ->withHeader('Content-Length', mb_strlen($content, '8bit') );
```